# Import Combined docx Document to R with the officer Package

Tags: r, import, docx, officer

I want to import and modify a docx file in R with the officer package. However, when I use the suggested functions, R imports only an empty data.frame. Consider the following example:

```
# Packages
library("magrittr")
library("officer")

# Create example docx on computer
my_doc1 <- read_docx() %>% 
  body_add_par('aaa', style = 'Normal')
my_doc2 <- read_docx() %>% 
  body_add_par('bbb', style = 'Normal')
my_doc3 <- read_docx() %>% 
  body_add_par('ccc', style = 'Normal')

print(my_doc1, target = 'C:/your-path/aaa.docx')
print(my_doc2, target = 'C:/your-path/bbb.docx')
print(my_doc3, target = 'C:/your-path/ccc.docx')

# Combine all docx
my_doc_all <- read_docx() %>% 
  body_add_docx(src = 'C:/your-path/aaa.docx') %>%
  body_add_docx(src = 'C:/your-path/bbb.docx') %>%
  body_add_docx(src = 'C:/your-path/ccc.docx')

# Print combined docx to computer
print(my_doc_all, target = 'C:/your-path/all.docx')
```

This is my current situation. Please note that this situation is given. The previous steps can not be changed.

Now, I want to import the combined docx file and modify it in R. According to the [documentation of officer (p. 26)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/officer/officer.pdf) and [this thread (answer by David Gohel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439684/how-to-extract-plain-text-from-docx-file-using-r), I should be able to do it with the following code:

```
# Read combined docx file
read_my_doc_all <- read_docx("C:/your-path/all.docx")

# Return dataset representing the docx document
docx_summary(my_doc_all)
```

However, the output is a data.frame with one empty row:

```
### doc_index content_type style_name text level num_id
### 1         1    paragraph         NA         NA     NA
```

I was researching on this problem myself and figured out that everything works fine, if we don't have to combine several docx documents in the forefront (as demonstrated in the beginning of this example). If we create a single file in R and export/import it, everything works fine.

How could I import a combined docx document to R with the officer package? If possible, I would like to stick to the officer package to keep the R syntax coherent.

Comment: officer is not reading embed documents. I just added a note in the documentation.

Comment: @David Gohel That's bad news. Is there eventually a work around? I noticed that everything works fine when I change something in the docx document manually. Would it somehow be possible to do such a change from within R?

Comment: Unfortunately no, R would need to drive Word program to let it add the content *inline*

Comment: @DavidGohel OK, thank you very much for the explanation!